# How do I skip to next entry if a key doesn't exist in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts, but a given entry might not exist. For example, I have the following dict where the entry for `c` is missing:

```py
g = { 
   'a': {'w': 14, 'x': 7, 'y': 9}, 
   'b': {'w': 9, 'c': 6},          # <- c is not in dict
   'w': {'a': 14, 'b': 9, 'y': 2}, 
   'x': {'a': 7, 'y': 10, 'z': 15}, 
   'y': {'a': 9, 'w': 2, 'x': 10, 'z': 11}, 
   'z': {'b': 6, 'x': 15, 'y': 11}
}
```

My current code

```py
start = 'a'
end = 'z'
queue, seen = [(0, start, [])], set()

while True:
    (distance, vertex, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
    if vertex not in seen:
        path = path + [vertex]
        seen.add(vertex)

        if vertex == end:
            print(distance, path)
            break                    # new line, based on solutions below
                                     # new line
        if vertex not in graph:      # new line
            continue                 # new line

        for (next_v, d) in graph[vertex].items():
            heapq.heappush(queue, (distance + d, next_v, path))
```

Right now I am getting the error:

`for (next_v, d) in graph[vertex].items():
 KeyError: 'c'`

**EDIT 1**

If key is not found in dict skip ahead.

**EDIT 2**

Even with the newly added code I get an error, this time:

    `(distance, vertex, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
IndexError: index out of range`

---

Here is the data file I use

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/citymapper-assets/citymapper-coding-test-graph.dat

Here is the file format:

```
<number of nodes>
<OSM id of node>
...
<OSM id of node>
<number of edges>
<from node OSM id> <to node OSM id> <length in meters>
...
<from node OSM id> <to node OSM id> <length in meters>
```

And here is the code to create the graph

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as reader:
    num_nodes = int(reader.readline())
    edges = []

    for line in islice(reader, num_nodes + 1, None):
        values = line.split()
        values[2] = int(values[2])
        edges.append(tuple(values))

graph = {k: dict(x[1:] for x in grp) for k, grp in groupby(sorted(edges), itemgetter(0))}
```

Change `start` and `end` to:

```
start = '876500321'
end = '1524235806'
```

Any help/advice is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `if vertex not in graph: continue`

Comment: `try/except KeyError` or `if c in g`

Comment: I guess the fact that the key listed in the sub-dictionary makes you jump anywhere in the dictionary. So the only way to avoid that scenario to clean the dictionary beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Before accessing `graph[vertex]`, make sure it is in the dict:

```
if vertex not in graph:
    continue

for (next_v, d) in graph[vertex].items():
    heapq.heappush(queue, (distance + d, next_v, path))
```

Comment: your solution ends in the following error: `(distance, vertex, path) = heapq.heappop(queue) IndexError: index out of range`

Comment: If vertex is not present in graph, what should be done?  Push onto the queue anyway, using default values for `next_v` and `d`?  I don't know your application, so I can't answer that question for you.

Comment: Skip that key and go to the next. All the given solutions should work.

Comment: The `while True` loop has no way to terminate, so after a solution is found, it still tries to pop from an empty heap.  Perhaps a `break` is needed in the `if vertex == end` branch?

Comment: I added a `break` and it worked.  Post your updated code with the `break`.

Comment: Your sample code works for me, except that I renamed `g` to `graph` and I added `import heapq`.

Comment: Your code also has no way to exit the loop if the desired path cannot be found. Are you sure that data file contains a solution?

Comment: The result based on the given two id's should be 2709 for distance.

Comment: Using the small data graph, your posted sample code works with the given modifications.  I'm not sure anyone is willing to dig through that huge dataset to find the issue.  Perhaps you could post a (much) smaller version of that dataset that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I am not sure at that point. I will try a different approach. Thanks John.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the vertex is in the graph before executing that final for loop:

```
if vertex in graph: 
    for (next_v, d) in graph[vertex].items():
        heapq.heappush(queue, (distance + d, next_v, path))
```

Comment: solution ends in the following error: `(distance, vertex, path) = heapq.heappop(queue) IndexError: index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `.get` and return a empty `{}` incase the key is not there, so that the `.items()` won't break like,

```
for (next_v, d) in graph.get(vertex, {}).items():
    heapq.heappush(queue, (distance + d, next_v, path))
```

Comment: solution ends in the following error: `(distance, vertex, path) = heapq.heappop(queue) IndexError: index out of range`